# Using "If exist/go to" inside a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a simple batch that will check for a file and if it exist go to the end.  If the file is not there then perform the task outlined.  The batch works as it should, however, it seems to ignore the file that "IF EXIST" part and rewrites the SIP-Dir.txt each time.  would like it to see the file and quit any further actions.  I am not a scripter but I have used small files like this many times.  Any help would be appreciated.  If my syntax is incorrect please let me know what it should be.

```
@echo off

IF EXIST %temp%\SIP-Dir.txt goto SKIP

TASKKILL /F /IM Communicator.exe
cd %LocalAPPData%\Microsoft\communicator
for /d %a in (sip*) do rd /s /q "%a"
Echo SIP DEL Complete > %temp%\SIP-Dir.txt

:SKIP
```

Comment: Comment out the "@echo off" to see what's getting parsed and "seen". Your IF statement is being seen, but the condition isn't true in your environment.

Comment: If you haven't resolved the problem already, you can check whether the `goto` itself is the problem by making it unconditional, i.e., just say `goto SKIP` without the `if exist` and see what happens. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might find that spaces in the path affect this.  Try it with the quotes below:

The first pause will fire if the file does not exist, during testing.  Remove it later.

The `for` command has been changed too, both to stop random folders from being deleted if the `CD` command fails, and to fix some errors in the variable name when used in a batch file.

```
IF EXIST "%temp%\SIP-Dir.txt" goto SKIP
pause
TASKKILL /F /IM Communicator.exe
for /d %%a in ("%LocalAPPData%\Microsoft\communicator\sip*") do rd /s /q "%%a"
Echo SIP DEL Complete > "%temp%\SIP-Dir.txt"
:skip
echo done
pause
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will give that a shot here soon and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not exist "%temp%\SIP-Dir.txt" (
    TASKKILL /F /IM Communicator.exe
    for /d %%a in ("%localappdata%\Microsoft\communicator\sip*") do rd /s /q "%%~fa"
    Echo SIP DEL Complete > "%temp%\SIP-Dir.txt"
)
```

In this case there is not need for the `goto` command. Instead of asking if the file exists, check if the file does not exist.

And as foxidrive states, it is better to quote the paths, especially when variables are used to build them.

Comment: Using brackets rather than goto doesn't change the logic, so it seems unlikely to solve the OPs problem.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, it does not change the functionality of the code, but changes the logic: you can not have problems with a `goto` if there is not `goto`. Anyway, it seems the problem is not the `goto` command per se but the involved paths. Probably.

Comment: It seemed unlikely to me that the goto was the problem, but on second thoughts I guess it's not impossible - there could be invisible embedded characters, for example, or if the label is on the last line of the file it might not be properly terminated.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, interesting idea. The label can be preceded by almost anything and it will still work. It is not necessary that the label ends in a CRLF. Not ending the line, ending it with only CR or LF or by a sequence of them will not interfere. Without involving unicode or pagecode problems, i don't see how to make it fail.